# Manage Live Tiles and Application Lifecycle

Tags: javascript, windows-8, microsoft-metro

I have an application using Live Tiles and updating them regulary. In case of a Windows 8 reboot, my application stops updating the Live Tiles, because it is terminated. The Metro preinstalled apps (Image Gallery, Finances) are getting this done. What can I do here?

Ressources:

- Working with Tiles: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh761490.aspx
- Application Lifecycle: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh464925.aspx

Answer (score 1):

You should use [periodic updates](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/Hh779721.aspx). Periodic updates can continue whether or not your app is running.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but periodic updates seem to be limited to polling xml-files in fairly long timespans of which the shortest is

`Windows.UI.Notifications.PeriodicUpdateRecurrence.halfHour`

I want to cycle through lots of images of which each one should be visible approx. 5 seconds. Or am I getting the concept of Periodic Updates wrong? 

If using the notification Queue `Windows.UI.Notifications.TileUpdateManager.createTileUpdaterForApplication().enableNotificationQueue(true);` I am limited to 5 Elements  that cycle through the Tile. This is not enough for me.